# Arduino giving random numbers reading IR

Tags: c++, arduino, rotation

im doing a tachometer with arduino uno and this is my code:

```
int ledPin = 13;               
volatile byte rpmcount;         
unsigned int rpm;       
unsigned long timeold;      
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

void rpm2()
 {
   rpmcount++; 
 }

void setup()
 {
   lcd.begin(16, 2);

   attachInterrupt(0, rpm2, FALLING);

   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
   rpmcount = 0;
   rpm = 0;
   timeold = 0;
 }

void loop()
 {
   delay(1000);
   detachInterrupt(0); 
   rpm = 30*1000/(millis() -Timeold)*rpmcount;                                       
   timeold = millis();                                                              
   rpmcount = 0;
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.print("RPM=");
   lcd.print(rpm);
   attachInterrupt(0, rpm2, FALLING);
  }
```

When i turn on arduino e starts giving me random numbers on *rpm* and i have no idea why. Even if i remove the IR it keeps showing the random numbers

Comment: Does the code even build? `Timeold` versus `timeold`. C++ is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes it builds. That was probably me when removing some comments @JoachimPileborg